# How to get a value from an object returned by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm doing something that should be fairly simple but I can't figure out how to get a certain value from the object that is returned by an ajax request.

[This screenshot should explain it.](http://screencast.com/t/fsdd1cI3)

I just need to be able to get the text returned where "Private video" is.

Answer (score 2):

In the `success` response, you can get the response data, and access the `responseText`

```
$.ajax({
  url:..

  success: function(data){
     alert(data.responseText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but:

> The text and xml types return the data with no processing. The data is
>   simply passed on to the success handler, either through the
>   **responseText** or responseXML property of the **jqXHR** object, respectively

and

> jqXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, **jqXHR**) {});

so I think it is correct:

```
$.ajax({
  url:..
}).done(function(data, txtStatus, jqXHR){
   console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

Check this and give me feedback.